# Private typedef and SFINAE in C++

Tags: c++, sfinae

I am trying to get intuition with SFINAE and apparently it should detect private access violation.

However, the following code does not compile with my clang++ 10.0.0-4ubuntu1.

```
class K{
    typedef void type;
};

template<typename T>
K::type f(T t) {}
void f(...) {}

    
int main() {
    f(K()); //error: 'x' is a private member of 'K'
}
```

Why is this not a case for SFINAE?

Comment: The S in SFINAE is for "substitution". What's substituted in `K::type`? Did you mean `typename T::type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`K::type` is not dependent on any template parameters, and therefore SFINAE does not apply.

If you instead use a dependent name, SFINAE will kick in, and the second overload of `f` would be selected.  For example:

```
class K{
    typedef void type;
};

template<typename T>
typename T::type f(T t) {}
void f(...) {}

    
int main() {
    f(K());
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/19xPoe)

Comment: But the argument does depend on the template parameter. Moreover, it just checked it with g++ and it does compile

Comment: @user2216953 No, `K::type` is exactly the same no matter what `T` is.  The fact that GCC accepts it seems like a bug, but I'm not sure; it may be "ill formed, no diagnostic required" or something.

Comment: Yes, the rules against an ill-formed non-dependent construct in a template and a template which could never be instantiated are both "no diagnostic required" - [\[temp.res\]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res#8).